# CartoDB restricts uploading only up to 250 columns

Tags: carto, csv, database

I had developed an application using cartodb.js which transforms a csv file uploaded in cartodb database to geometries in map. The application works fine when there are 230 columns in csv file and the upload is not success if i tried to import 309 columns into cartodb. Is there any other way to increase the column count or any alternate solutions?

Answer (score 4):

CartoDB have a limit on the number of columns that can be contained inside a dataset.
If you have more than 250 columns of data, you would need to structure the file in a different way in order to be able to generate a dataset in CartoDB.

You can find more information [here](http://www.postgresql.org/about/).

Comment: Thanks for the response oriolbx. It was given that Maximum Columns per Table is 250 - 1600 depending on column types in the link you had mentioned. I would like to know what column types can be used in cartodb for more number of columns and also is there any option to increase the block size ?